# What kind of output does the "protractor-ng-hint-plugin" generates?

Tags: angularjs, plugins, protractor

I'm currently researching on "**protractor-ng-hint-plugin**" on how its used and what output it generates to see if it would be beneficial for my project. But, there is very little to none documentation on this plugin.
Only meaningful doc out there is https://github.com/angular/protractor-ng-hint-plugin .
I've added

```
plugins: [
{
    package: 'protractor-ng-hint-plugin'
}
```

and I've verified that the plugin is loaded during the test by using `--troubleshoot` flag.

Has anyone used this plugin? If yes, what output does it generates?

Answer (score 0):

If your app has the [`angular-hint.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular-hint) loaded and `ng-hint` activated, the `protractor-ng-hint-plugin` would report Angular best practices violations on the command-line. Try to run tests against these sample applications and see warnings on the console:

- https://github.com/angular/protractor-ng-hint-plugin/tree/master/testapp
- https://github.com/angular/angular-hint/tree/master/examples